# structure of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics

I have a data frame that contains a long list of entries.

[image: here is an image of my dataframe]

I've indexed them by protein accession numbers. The problem is, they are repeating because some of the proteins consist of multiple domains. I want to make the protein accession numbers the main entries (and it'd have information about how many domains it has - domain_count) and the domains of those proteins to be subentries. For example when I type:

```
df_filtered.loc['P43098_e', 'domain_count']
```

it returns the number 5 for each domain (5 times). I want it to print 5 only once since P43098_e would be the main entry to which information about domain_count is directly assigned.
Could someone help me, please?

Comment: No Images please share the data as a code (preferably) or text. here are the stackoverflow guidelines  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: added a solution, is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you're looking for?

if you share the data as a code, I'll be able to hare the result too

```
df_filtered.loc[df_filtered['protein_accession'] == 'P43098_e', 'domain_count'][:1].values[0]
```

```
(df_filtered.loc[df_filtered['protein_accession'] == 'P43098_e', 'domain_count']
 .head(1)
 .squeeze())
```

OR

```
(df_filtered[df_filtered['protein_accession'] == 'P43098_e']['domain_count']
 .head(1)
 .squeeze())
```

OR

Either you need to reset_index() on df_fitered and run above solutions
OR add reset_filtered within the statement, like

```
(df_filtered.reset_index()[df_filtered.reset_index()['protein_accession'] == 'P43098_e']['domain_count']
 .head(1)
 .squeeze())
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I don't know why but I got the KeyError for both of your suggestions. I restarted and run all on jupyter notebook but I got the same result, even though I replaced '_' with space.

Comment: it means column names not found. Can you do a reset_index() on df_filtered?

Comment: updated the answer, check and advise please @Aurinko